# Retags should not bump a post

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, retagging

I think (following the [cd](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cd) incident) that retags, as a maintenance operation, should not bump the question to the front page. What do you think?

Comment: or in general, you can wait for community consensus, and space out the edits.

Comment: Retagging can change the meaning of a post, and is an operation that requires community review. That's why they're bumped. [related topic on MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122567/allow-non-bumping-minor-edits-but-review-them-on-review).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a proper way to do retags - make a proposal, wait for community consensus, create a list of questions that should be edited, and look at editing the questions gradually. I've done this a few times - for example, with respect to SAS, and i believe MC.

Editing old posts shouldn't be that common, IMO - the one case where it was necessary was when we had to fix image links.

I'd note that i've only seen someone get temporarily banned for overenthusiastic editing once, so its not a huge problem.

Comment: „I'd note that i've only seen someone get temporarily banned for overenthusiastic editing once” — was that me?

Comment: presumably, did you get your name changed?>

Comment: Don’t understand.

Comment: I seem to remember the user being called MUST DO RETAGS, or something to that vein.

Comment: Then it was not me. I was `URGE TO RETAG` (only on meta though)

Comment: ah, yes, that was that. It was probably you

Comment: Or, if the retags can be done all at once, post the proposal here on meta & a moderator can carry forwarding with the mass retag